# ERROR ITMS-90514: "Missing Code Signing Entitlement. Use of the 'network-authentication' background mode in 'Payload/xxx.app/xxx'

Tags: ios, wifi, nehotspothelper

My app has added the WiFi configuration function. All the relevant permissions have been configured, and there is no problem with the package test.

But when preparing to pack and upload to the app store,

> ERROR ITMS-90514: "Missing Code Signing Entitlement. Use of the
>   'network-authentication' background mode in 'Payload/xxx.app/xxx'
>   requires either the 'com.apple.developer.CaptiveNetworkPlugin' or
>   'com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper' entitlement."

is reported as wrong

when add

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper</key>
<true/>
```

Xcode compilation will report error :

> -1: Provisioning profile "xxx" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper entitlement. (in target
>   'xxx)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgDO6.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means your provisioning profile doesn't include that capability. Now if you have used a provisioning profile created manually then you need to login to your developer account and add edit your profile and add other capabilities or you can create a new provisioning profile(recommended as apple may not allow adding new capabilities in existing profile) with all the capabilities.

And the better way is automatic `code signing`. In that case, you need to add your account in the Xcode(from the preference of the Xcode). Then from general you can check `Automatically manage signing` and there is no need for certificate and provisioning profile. Then whatever capabilities you will add will automatically be included with your auto-generated profile. You don't require to manage anything manually.